# Python Filtering OData Entity by Parent - Requests Library

Tags: python, python-requests, filtering, odata

I have an OData API I'm trying to query using the Python Requests library.  I'm trying to filter a table based on the parent table for an incremental data pull.   The children tables don't use a `last_update_date`, but I can get this date from the parent as the parent's `last_updated_date` changes even if the change is in a child table.  Note that in my example, `employees` is the parent entity of `employee_texts`.

My code looks like the below:

```
data = requests.get(
    endpoint_url + "employee_texts"
    , auth=(api_username, api_password)
    , params={
        "$filter": "employees/LastModifiedDate gt 2023-11-15T00:00:00.00Z",
        "$format": "json"
    }
    , verify=True
)
```

If I run this, I get the below error:

> {'error': {'code': '',
> 'message': 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: type'}}

Please note that this code works as expected:

```
data = requests.get(
    endpoint_url + "employees"
    , auth=(api_username, api_password)
    , params={
        "$filter": "LastModifiedDate gt 2023-11-15T00:00:00.00Z",
        "$format": "json"
    }
    , verify=True
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `employees` is a collection then you need to use `any` operator in `$filter` query.

```
data = requests.get(
    endpoint_url + "employee_texts"
    , auth=(api_username, api_password)
    , params={
        "$filter": "employees/any(e:e/LastModifiedDate gt 2023-11-15T00:00:00.00Z)",
        "$format": "json"
    }
    , verify=True
)
```

Comment: So as it turns out, the related table's navigation property is set to false by the parent column.  I assume this means I'm out of luck